# Book suggestion for real analysis help.

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, self-learning, book-recommendation

I am looking for a good book to supplement my class book on analysis.
I am struggling with concepts and I would like a book that can help me learn how to learn analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that one book that has really helped me this semester is *How to  Think About Analysis* by Laura Alcock. She goes through many of the concepts that are in an introductory analysis class and some best practices for studying the material, as it can be very difficult if you do not approach it the right way.

Comment: Thanks! I have heard of this book I will give it a try.

Answer (score 3):

1) Charalambos D. Aliprantis, *Principles of Real Analysis*.

2) J. Yeh, *Theory of Measure and Integration*.

3) Sterling K. Berberian, *Fundamentals of Real Analysis*.

4) Russell A. Gordon, *Integrals of Lebesgue, Denjoy, Perron, and Henstock*.

Comment: Are there many exercises in these books?

Comment: A bunch of them, don't worry.

Answer (score 3):

When I was learning introductory real analysis, the text that I found the most helpful was Stephen Abbott's Understanding Analysis. It's written both very cleanly and concisely, giving it the advantage of being extremely readable, all without missing the formalities of analysis that are the focus at this level. While it's not as thorough as Rudin's Principles of Analysis or Bartle's Elements of Real Analysis, it is a great text for a first or second pass at really understanding single, real variable analysis.